# How is the default value for CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL determined at runtime by MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Per the Microsoft Documentation for MS SQL 2008R2,

> 1)If SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS is not specified, the setting of the CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL database option applies
>   2)The setting of SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is set at execute or run time and not at parse time

I interpret this as

> As soon as you connect to the database without providing a SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL command , it will set it by default from the database option

To verify this, I created a database called `Test` with option `CONCATENATE NULL YIELDS NULL=FALSE` and a login which defaults to this database and execute the following SQL statements using SQLCMD.

```
set nocount on
declare @dbName sysname

select @dbName = DB_NAME() 
select 'I am in database =',@dbName


select 'The CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL setting is =', is_concat_null_yields_null_on 
from sys.databases
where name = @dbName

IF ( (4096 & @@options) = 4096 ) 
begin
   select 'CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is ON' 
end
else
begin
   select 'CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is OFF' 
end
go
```

The output of the above SQL is

```
I am in database = Test

                                         is_concat_null_yields_null_on

The CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL setting is = 0



CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is ON
```

Why is the `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON` when it should have been OFF as the database Test had this option set to OFF ?

Is my interpretation of the M.S document incorrect OR is the documentation itself wrong ?

I know that this feature is marked for deprecation but my understanding is that it is still active for MS SQL2008R2.

Answer (score 1):

The database options aren't very relevant because the various client libraries and tools all have their own defaults anyway which they set on your behalf at connection time.

Erland Sommarskog [lists them here](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#defaultsettings)

[image]